# Cómo actualizar una factura con una condición que compruebe si hay datos diferentes?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Este es mi código:

```
public function update_remito()
{
$post = $this->input->post();

$idremito = $this->uri->segment('3');

$data = array(
      'id_cliente' => $post['id_cliente'],
      'razonsocial_cliente' => $post['nombre_cliente'],
      'fecha_remito'  => $post['fecha'],
      'total_remito'  => $post['total_remito']
  );

$this->db->where('id_remito', $idremito);
$this->db->update('remitosclientes', $data);

$q = $this->db->select('id_factura')->get('detalleremitos')->result_array();

$db_id=array();
$update=array();

foreach ($q as $key => $value) {
    $db_id[$key]=$value['id_factura'];
}

for ($i=0;$i<count($post['id_producto']);$i++) {
    $update = array(
  'id_factura' => $idremito,
  'id_producto' => $post['id_producto'][$i],
  'nombre_producto' => $post['nombre_producto'][$i],
  'cantidad' => $post['stock'][$i],
  'precio' => $post['precio'][$i],
  'color' => $post['color'][$i],
  'talle' => $post['talle'][$i]
  );

    $update_query = $this->db->where_in('id_factura', $idremito)
     ->get('detalleremitos')->result  ();
    var_dump($update_query);
    if (count($update_query) > 0) {
      $this->db->insert('detalleremitos', $update);//update if ids exist

    } else {
        $this->db->update('detalleremitos', $update, $idremito);//insert if does not exist
    }
  }
}
```

El problema es que no actualiza solo agrega las líneas sin diferenciar lo que hay en la base de datos, lo que necesito hacer es un factura, y que esa factura pueda ser actualizada y que el código detecte los cambios y los guarde, pero que no pierda los datos no cambiados, no se si me explico, espero su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a utilizar una clave primaria, como por ejemplo un identificador de factura, puedes utilizar

> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

con esto porás actualizar la factura si esta ya existe en la base de datos o insertarla si no existe. Un ejemplo sería algo así:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1_claveprimaria, campo2, campo3) VALUES ($valor1, $valor2, $valor3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE campo2 = VALUES(campo2), campo3 = VALUES(campo3)
```

Al utilizar VALUES(campoX) lo que haces es utilizar el mismo valor que se iba a insertar para actualizar, pero podrías utilizar cualquier otro valor directo.

Comment: genial! lo voy a intentar